# IntelliJ IDEA does not add JPA facet

Tags: java, hibernate, maven, jpa, intellij-idea

I have a maven project with JPA and Hibernate:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>jakarta.persistence</groupId>
    <artifactId>jakarta.persistence-api</artifactId>
    <version>3.1.0</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate.orm</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
    <version>6.2.13.Final</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate.orm</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-envers</artifactId>
    <version>6.2.13.Final</version>
</dependency>

<!-- API for 2nd Level Cache -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate.orm</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-jcache</artifactId>
    <version>6.2.13.Final</version>
</dependency>
```

But IntelliJ IDEA doesn't recognize it and also doesn't add the JPA facet to the project settings.

Yes, I can manually add the JPA facet to the project settings. However, this is stored in the .iml file, which should not be shared via VCS. ([share project settings](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/configure-project-settings.html#list-of-ignored-files)).

The documentation ([Add framworks](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/adding-support-for-frameworks-and-technologies.html)) also describes that facets should be added through Maven and not through project settings.

What do I need to do to make IntelliJ IDEA automatically add the JPA facet? Are the dependencies not enough?

**Update1: Info added**

The detection setting is enabled in the project:
[image]

Comment: Are you sure framework auto detection is not disabled? Please share the [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) on GitHub.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have received the following information from Support. According to [IDEA-308710](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-308710/JPA-do-not-autoimport-facets-from-Maven-and-Gradle) IDEA no longer automatically creates JPA Facets and provides the corresponding functionality without them.

Answer (score 0):

Now we have to add the JPA facets manually.

**Edit**: According to the next tutorial, https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/adding-support-for-frameworks-and-technologies.html, following the steps:

1. Select the project folder with a click, and press Ctrl+Shift+A.
2. Then type 'Add Framework Support', this will open Add Framework Support Window
3. Select the necessary framework from the list. In my case was Groovy.
4. Once selected, click ok.
   That worked for me.

I hope this edit helps better.

Comment: Cann you please provide some examples without links? They may be broken in future.

Comment: I tried to add steps of what I did. I hope it helps.